# How to query two objects in document with orderBy clause in Firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with documents structure something like this:

```
{
    departments: {
        dept1: true,
        dept2: true
    },
    roles: {
        role1: true,
        role2: true
    },
    created_at: timestamp
}
```

How to query above collection to get all documents with dept1 and role1 in ordered by timestamp.

I checked firebase documentation here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

But it only answers how to get ordered results when we are querying single object in a document.

Also, if its not possible with this document structure, then how should I structure document/collection to get the desired result in a performant way as this will be most frequent query in the App

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ref.where("departments.dept1", "=", true).where("roles.role1", "=", true).orderBy("timestamp")`?

Comment: As per the documentation link provided, give one of object properties timestamp like for eg. roles.role1 = 22423425 and then orderby will work, but that approach does not work with two object keys :(

Comment: Ah, I was already wondering why another sample suggested it could (since I have no idea how the backend would implement it efficiently). In that case you'll have to do the order-by-timestamp in the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are definitely able to make the query below if you create an index to it in the Firebase Console.

```
this.refCollection.where('departaments.dept1', '==',true).where('roles.role1', '==', true).orderBy('timestamp')
```

**However**, this approach won’t work in you case because you want to dynamically add data to your database, so it would be impractical to make a new index every time a new department or role is added. A solution for that would be to denormalize your database.

You can follow this example and adapt to your case:

First create a field for each department that is added like below.

> dept1_role1_timestamp: 1514925588675

Your document would look like this:

[image]

Then create a method like this one where you pass by parameter which department and role you want to get from the database.

```
getDocumentsByDepartamentAndRole(dept, role) {
    return this.collectionRef.orderBy(`${dept}_${role}_timestamp`).get();
}
```

Now you gonna be able to search dynamically without having to create an index for each new department  that is added. Generally we denormalize our database when we need to guarantee a better read performance. But keep in mind that your write will loose performance because every time you want to update a role for your department,  you will have to update the extra field you created for make your query possible. 
Another solution would be to sort you array in the client side. Both ways will work.

By default Firestore does not require additional indexes for queries that only use equality clauses, clearly that is not you case since you are making use of a range clause.

To get to know more about how Firestore indexes work you can read on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: Thanks Mateus Forgiarini da Silva, this works. but the issue is department & roles are dynamically added to the document, hence creating indexes before can not be done :(. I guess I need to approach this differently with some different document design.

Comment: huum, got your point, I updated the answer, you can make your query by denormalizing the database. This technique is used in the Realtime Database because there your queries can only filter by one key at a time. Just follow the example and it will work :)

Comment: Thanks Mateus Forgiarini da Silva, creating keys to maintain flat structure worked.